# Efficiency of using IEqualityComparer in Dictionary vs HashCode and Equals()

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dictionary

The title is pretty much clear I think.

I was wondering if there's a certain efficiency overhead when using `IEqualityComparer` in a `Dictionary<K,V>` how does it all work when providing one?

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Is it Faster?**

Coming from a gamedev perspective, if your key is a value type (struct, primitive, enum, etc.) providing your own `EqualityComparer<T>` is significantly faster - due to the fact the `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` boxes the value.

As a real-world example, the Managed DirectX billboard sample used to run at ~30% of the speed of the C++ version; where all the other samples were running at ~90%. The reason for this was that the billboards were being sorted using the default comparer (and thus being boxed), as it turns out 4MB of data was being copied around every frame thanks to this.

**How does it work?**

`Dictionary<K,V>` will provide `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to itself via the default constructor. What the default equality comparer does is (basically, notice how much boxing occurs):

```
public void GetHashCode(T value)
{
   return ((object)value).GetHashCode();
}

public void Equals(T first, T second)
{
   return ((object)first).Equals((object)second);
}
```

**Why would I ever use it?**

It's quite common to see this kind of code (when trying to have case-insensitive keys):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict.Add(myParam.ToUpperInvariant(), fooParam);
// ...
var val = dict[myParam.ToUpperInvariant()];
```

This is really wasteful, it is better to just use a StringComparer on the constructor:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

**Is it faster (redux)?**

In this specific scenario it is a lot faster, because ordinal string comparisons are the fastest type of string comparison you can do. A quick benchmark:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var d1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    var d2 = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    d1.Add("FOO", 1);
    d2.Add("FOO", 1);

    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    s.Start();
    RunTest1(d1, "foo");
    s.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("ToUpperInvariant: {0}", s.Elapsed);

    s.Reset();
    s.Start();
    RunTest2(d2, "foo");
    s.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("OrdinalIgnoreCase: {0}", s.Elapsed);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void RunTest1(Dictionary<string, int> values, string val)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        values[val.ToUpperInvariant()] = values[val.ToUpperInvariant()];
    }
}

static void RunTest2(Dictionary<string, int> values, string val)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        values[val] = values[val];
    }
}

// ToUpperInvariant: 00:00:04.5084119
// OrdinalIgnoreCase: 00:00:02.1211549
// 2x faster.
```

**Reservations**

It is possible to eliminate the boxing overhead by implementing an interface on a struct (such as `IEquatable<T>`). However, there are many surprising rules for when boxing occurs under these circumstances so I would recommend using the paired interface (e.g. `IEqualityComparer<T>` in this case) if at all possible.

Comment: Great answer but I think you should have mentioned `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` first checks if the type implements `IEquatable<T>` and if so, uses the implementation; which means you don't _have to_ supply a custom comparer just to avoid boxing if your value type implements `IEquatable<T>` interface.

Comment: @ŞafakGür using interfaces to access value types will box them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995606/boxing-occurrence-in-c-sharp

Comment: Calling `Foo(IEquatable<int> obj)` using an int will box it, but calling `Bar<T>(T obj) where T : IEquatable<int>` won't. This is pretty much why generics exist.

Comment: @ŞafakGür nope. Compile it and check the IL - accessing struct methods via interfaces will box - the reason is that structs lack an ITable+VTable. This is why IEqualityComparer exists. I saved you the trouble: https://gist.github.com/jcdickinson/9051956#file-program-bar-il-L16 (IL0003 is a box instruction)

Comment: It boxes the struct because your sample calls `Object.Equals` ([see IL000E](https://gist.github.com/jcdickinson/9051956#file-program-bar-il-L18)), not `IEquatable<T>.Equals`. How can compiler know if obj1 or obj2 is a `MyEquatableThing` with a signature like this: `bool Bar<T>(T obj1, T obj2) where T : IEquatable<MyEquatableThing>`? Change your generic type constraint to `where T : IEquatable<T>` and check the IL again, there is no `box` instruction.

Comment: @ŞafakGür thanks, that got rid of the box instruction (updated the gist). I'll update the answer with a more correct conclusion when I get home.

Answer (score 25):

Jonathan has a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7145953/704144) that points out how, using the right equality comparer improves the performance and Jon clarifies in [his great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7144006/704144) that `Dictionary<K, V>` always uses an `IEqualityComparer<T>` which is `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` unless you specify another.

The thing I'd like to touch upon is the role of `IEquatable<T>` interface when you use the default equality comparer.

When you call the `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`, it uses a cached comparer if there is one. If it's the first time you're using the default equality comparer for that type, it calls a method called `CreateComparer` and caches the result for later use. Here is the trimmed and simplified implementation of `CreateComparer` in .NET 4.5:

```
var t = (RuntimeType)typeof(T);

// If T is byte,
// return a ByteEqualityComparer.

// If T implements IEquatable<T>,
if (typeof(IEquatable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(t))
    return (EqualityComparer<T>)
           RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstanceForAnotherGenericParameter(
               (RuntimeType)typeof(GenericEqualityComparer<int>), t);

// If T is a Nullable<U> where U implements IEquatable<U>,
// return a NullableEqualityComparer<U>

// If T is an int-based Enum,
// return an EnumEqualityComparer<T>

// Otherwise return an ObjectEqualityComparer<T>
```

But what does it mean for types that implement `IEquatable<T>`?
Here, the definition of `GenericEqualityComparer<T>`:

```
internal class GenericEqualityComparer<T> : EqualityComparer<T>
    where T: IEquatable<T>
// ...
```

The magic happens in the generic type constraint (`where T : IEquatable<T>` part) because using it does *not* involve boxing if `T` is a value type, no casting like `(IEquatable<T>)T` is happening here, which is the primary benefit of generics.

So, let's say we want a dictionary that maps integers to strings.
What happens if we initialize one using the default constructor?

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

- We know that a dictionary uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` unless we specify another.
- We know that `EqualityComparer<int>.Default` will check if int implements `IEquatable<int>`.
- We know that `int` (`Int32`) implements `IEquatable<Int32>`.

First call to `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` will create and cache a generic comparer which may take a little but when initialized, it's a strongly typed `GenericEqualityComparer<T>` and using it will cause no boxing or unnecessary overhead whatsoever.

And all the subsequent calls to `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` will return the cached comparer, which means the overhead of initialization is one-time only for each type.

---

So what does it all mean?

- **Do implement** a custom equality comparer if `T` does not implement `IEquatable<T>` **or** its implementation of `IEquatable<T>` does not do what you want it to do.
  (i.e. `obj1.Equals(obj2)` doesn`t give you the desired result.)

Using of `StringComparer` in Jonathan's answer is a great example why you would specify a custom equality comparer.

- **Do not implement** a custom equality comparer for the sake of performance if `T` implements `IEquatable<T>` **and** the implementation of `IEquatable<T>` does what you want it to do.
  (i.e. `obj1.Equals(obj2)` gives you the desired result).

In the latter case, use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` instead.

Answer (score 10):

`Dictionary<,>` *always* uses an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` - if you don't pass one, it uses [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx). So the efficiency will depend on how efficient your implementation is compared with `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` (which just delegates to `Equals` and `GetHashCode`).

Comment: @jtbandes: If you see this, could you stop changing my posts? I prefer to leave everything in ASCII...

Comment: Whoop, sure. Can you consider using "--" then? It's more readable, at least in my opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced huge trouble to make an identical `EqualityComparer` ... critical section was`GetHashCode` which was generating duplicate key when targeting `object[]` and records are more then 20k .. below is the solution

```
public class ObJectArrayEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<object[]>
{ 
    public bool Equals(object[] x, object[] y)
    {
        if (x.Length != y.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            var tempX = x[i];
            var tempY = y[i];
            if ((tempX==null || tempX ==DBNull.Value) 
                && (tempY == null || tempY == DBNull.Value))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (!tempX.Equals(tempY) 
                && !System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(tempX, tempY))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object[] obj)
    {
        if (obj.Length == 1)
        {
            return obj[0].GetHashCode();
        }

        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length; i++)
        {
            result = result + (obj[i].GetHashCode() * (65 + i));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```